# Vue.js doesn't render loop properly when chaning value through the v-model

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group m-b-5">
            <label for="row" class="control-label col-sm-4">Row</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="number" id="row" v-model="row_no" min="0">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group m-b-5">
            <label for="column" class="control-label col-sm-4">Column</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="number" id="column" v-model="col_no" min="0">
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr v-for="row of row_no">
                <td   v-for="col of col_no" v-if="!(row==1&&col==1)">
                        <span>
                            {{ row }} {{ col }}
                        </span>
                </td>
                <td  v-else class="v-hidden">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                row_no:5,
                col_no:5,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am getting the data as follows in the above scenario [image: Before scenatio]

But after I change the value in the row from the form I didn't get the expected result as I wanted . It shows data like this when I put row=6
[image: Not expected answer]

The format I want is like this when I put row=6 when I put data in the form should be like this [image]

Am I doing something wrong . Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your data after typing in an input form holds a string and not a number.

Try to change your form to

```
<input type="number" id="row" v-model.number="row_no" min="0">
```

I hope this helps. For the future, if you have debugging problems like this, I would install 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

You can check for each component what the data/computed values are and see what type of data a variable holds.

Comment: I installed vue.js devtools too . I have input type of  number too . If I changed the value from dev tools it shows the expected answer but not from form

Comment: Yes you need to add `v-model.number` instead of `v-model` (I had the example for col instead of row, since you were asking about rows I changed the example and forgot to add `.number` again. I have now edited it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer